clusterIP with valid ssl
I have the following scenario:
I have a Kubernetes cluster, where I have both my front-end and back-end in the same cluster. The front-end is publicly exposed and has a valid SSL certificate, while my back-end is internally accessible (ClusterIP).
When I make a request from my front-end to my back-end, there's a communication error because my back-end requires a valid certificate, but how can I issue a valid certificate for an internal cluster API that isn't publicly exposed?
I need a solution that works in a production environment.
Attempts:
I tried using the same certificate from the front-end on the back-end, but encountered a host ownership error with the certificate. I used a self-signed certificate on the back-end, but the front-end doesn't recognize it.

What do you mean with "front-end"? Is that a web page, executed in a browser?
